# (C++ / CLI) Set contents of textbox to content of a .txt

Tags: c++-cli, iostream, fstream

I am looking to set the contents of a textbox to that of a .txt file,
however I cannot get it to work. I have a button which would "refresh" the
content of the textbox to that of the .txt file, here is the code I am using:

```
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    std::ifstream dat1("DataStore.txt");
    String^ textHolder;
    if (dat1.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline(dat1, line) )
        {
            textHolder += line.c_str;
        }
        textBox1->Text = textHolder;
        dat1.close();
    }
    else textBox1->Text = "Unable to open file";
}
```

I get these 2 errors when compiling the program:

```
error C3867: 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str' to create a pointer to member

error C2297: '+=' : illegal, right operand has type 'const char *(__thiscall std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::* )(void) throw() const'
```

How do I make this work?

NOTE: I am trying to display the whole .txt file's contents in the textbox

Comment: How about trying to write actual C++ code. "String^" is not valid C++. It's Microsoft-only mutation of the standard C++ language.

Comment: This neither C++ nor is it calling the Windows API. If you are using C++/CLI, use the appropriate tag. If this is targeting .NET, use the appropriate tag. And please do remove those that aren't. (Surprisingly, developers these days don't even know the programming language or target platform they are using anymore. [Does Visual Studio Rot the Mind?](http://charlespetzold.com/etc/DoesVisualStudioRotTheMind.html) It sure looks like it.)

Comment: Well whenever I use "String" instead of "String^" it gives me an error saying that "no default constructor exists for class System::String"

Comment: So? Ever since when was `String` (aka `System::String`) the same thing as `std::string`? Get a few books, and don't use an IDE, until you know programming.

Comment: @NopeNope It's going to pay dividends for you to work out what language you are working with. Clue: this is not C++

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought it was C++, but if it's not what is it?

Comment: Well, I challenge you to try and find out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use C++/CLI you may as well take advantage of .net. You can use the `File` class to read the file for you:

```
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    textBox1->Text = System::IO::File::ReadAllText("DataStore.txt");
}
```

You'll need to hope that the process working directory contains that file. In a GUI app you are better served by specifying full paths to files, since the working directory is typically ill-defined.

If you are trying to learn C++, then perhaps a .net C++/CLI WinForms application is not the place to start.

Comment: I'd assumed you had a `using System::IO` namespace declaration. Without that you'd need to fully qualify the name. As per the latest update.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to end method c_str, change it to c_str()

Comment: right, so is there any way to do what I am asking or not?

Comment: @NopeNope So after compilation, your code does not work? Did you debug it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `line` is probably std::string, not System::String, check compilation error.

Comment: fair enough, missed that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "line" is std::string, because thats the only thing "getline()" will accept